# React native navigation after state change in redux

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I am using `react-redux` and `react-native's navigation` in my app. My goal is of navigate after successful API call from `Screen A` -> `Screen B` -> `Screen C` and so on.

This is what I'm doing in the app.

1. On Screen A, button is pressed, and an redux action is generated.
2. Action is internally calling an API and getting result and dispatching event to reducer state.
3. After reducer's state gets updated (Success cases), I wanted to navigate to Screen B.
4. Again same 1-3 steps for Screen B to Screen C.

I did tried following approaches:

1. Adding navigation code in `componentWillReceiveProps`:

Problem with this approach is, its calling all the `componentWillReceiveProps` of navigation stack. This is rendering current screen multiple times before navigating to next screen (I observed this behaviour from `Screen B` -> `Screen C`)

2. Adding navigation code `render` method itself and `returning null`.

Again problem here is, what if I have multiple `reducer` mapped in one screen. Again I will be navigating more than once if both `reducer` changes.

3. I thought of using `EventListener's`, but than I have to keep track of adding and removing them.

Any ideas on how can I achieve this.

Thanks